# Display Post title PHP function doesn't work

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Sup ,I have added 2 posts in BO , and trying to display title of posts with php , but it doesn't work , should i add any any additional function to functions php or not? 
Instead of post title it display - "Home" - page title . where i wrong?

Here is some code

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row"id="blog">
   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-md-5"id="blog-post">

<div class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></div>
<div class="post-txt"><?php echo get_excerpt(); ?></div>

</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need $post_id in your get_the_title() function because you are in a loop. In which file is this code ? Maybe you are not in a query.
Try this before your if statement and show me what you get :

```
    <?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    var_dump($queried_object);
    ?>
```

Comment: object(WP_Post)#1178 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(8) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2019-07-04 09:47:19" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2019-07-04 09:47:19" ["post_content"]=>

Comment: this file in index php

Comment: I don't know why it still display - page title not post title , but if I for example put a post id for ex '64' it works

Comment: Once again you don't need $post_id. You could try with get_the_id() instead

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code.

if ( have_posts() ) {

```
        // Load posts loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="post-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php
        }
    }
```